# ¿Como podría calcular año de nacimiento a partir de la respuesta?

Tags: python

```
edad=input("¿Que edad tienes?")

year = '2020'

a = year - edad

if edad.isdigit():
    print("Buena edad")

else: edad=int(input("Error en la edad ¿Que edad tienes?"))

print("Este es tu año de nacimiento:", a)
```

Comment: por favor dale a [edit] y pon formato al código, así como indica claramente qué tienes, qué falla, etc

Answer (score 0):

Tu codigo está casi perfecto, solo necesita un detalle.
El ingreso de edad es un 'string', por lo que restar cadenas de 'string' no es nada lógico.

Lo que debes restar, son numeros, int, float, etc... en este caso int.
Lo que puedes hacer es lo sgte entonces.

```
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-
def func():
  year = '2020'

  while True:
    try:
      edad = int(raw_input("¿Que edad tienes?"))
      break
    except ValueError:
      print("No es un numero")
      continue

  print("Numero Valido")
  a = int(year) - int(edad)
  print("Este es tu anio de nacimiento:", a)

func()
```

Comment: si deja el calculo de `a` antes del if, siempre le va a dar error el código porque si ingresan una cadena no numérica hacer parse `int` falla. y al llegar la `else` su ejecución terminaría sin realizar el calculo, así que este código siempre sigue estando incorrecto.

Comment: Prueba ingresando "HOLA"

Comment: Actualizado para las personas que no leen

Comment: Acaba de editar su respuesta a una manera correcta para Python 3.x (y no python 2.x), no es que no leamos. Y tomó ideas de las respuestas de los demás.

Comment: exacto !!! pero estas personas dale que dale que editara la respuesta anterior, que esto que lo otro.. ahi tienen.

Comment: re-editado de nuevo para ti @WillyGuevara

Comment: @Excorpion pero cuando caiga a la `except` el programa terminaría, lo correcto es que le vuelva a preguntar la edad.

Comment: Solo manda la funcion de nuevo... en serio tengo que poner todo 3 veces por que 2 personas no se dieron cuenta que era python 2 ???

Comment: @WillyGuevara ahi esta lo que faltaba... recursividad...

Answer (score 0):

Debe realizar varios ajustes en su codigo:

1. Poner la variable year de una vez como valor entero `year = 2020`
2. Poner el calculo de `a` dentro del `if` validando que lo que ha ingresado el usuario es un dígito/numero, pero usando mejor `type()` de python porque si le ingresan un entero le va a dar error ya que una variable entera no tiene `isdigit()`
3. Mejor hacer una función ya que en la parte del `else` el sistema terminaría la ejecución sin realizar él calculo, entonces allí (`else`) debemos llamar de nuevo a la misma función para que todo comience de nuevo.
4. El siguiente ejemplo es compatible con python 2 y python 3

Quedaría así:

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
def pregunta():
    edad = input("¿Que edad tienes?\n")

    year = 2020
    if (type(edad) is str and edad.isnumeric()) or type(edad) is int:
        a = year - edad if type(edad) is int else int(edad, 10)
        print("Este es tu año de nacimiento:", a)
    
    else:
        print("\n>>> La edad ingresada es incorrecta.\n\n")
        pregunta()

pregunta()
```

Comment: yo ejecuté este codigo en mi terminal y si usted ingresa un entero ya python lo toma como entero y no como cadena de números que requieran parse `int`, lo puede probar usted para verificar @CandidMoe

Comment: No me había percatado de que estás trabajando con Python 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es que `input` siempre devuelve una cadena, por lo que hay que usar `int` para convertir lo leido a un entero.

Lo que haremos será pedir la edad y validar que sea numérica usando `isnumeric`. En tal caso, salimos del `while`. Si no, volvemos a pedir la edad.

```
while True:
    edad=input("¿Que edad tienes?")
    if edad.isnumeric():
        break
edad = int(edad)
```

Como vas a operar con años, inicializa la variable con un entero, no con una cadena:

```
year = 2020
```

En resumen, el código queda así:

```
while True:
    edad=input("¿Que edad tienes?")
    if edad.isnumeric():
        break
edad = int(edad)

year = 2020
a = year - edad
print("Este es tu año de nacimiento:", a)
```

Comment: Acabo de probar su codigo y a mi no me funciona, da error si ingresa un numero entero, le comparto el error que da:

`¿Que edad tienes?43    
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/sample.py", line 4, in <module>
    if edad.isnumeric():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isnumeric'
`

Comment: Acabo de volver a probar y en efecto, funciona pero en python 3, no en python 2, quería dejar eso claro, que este código no trabaja en python 2

Comment: @WillyGuevara. Ya es hora de migrar a Python 3.x y dejar en el pasado al 2.x.

Comment: compatibilidad para atrás es importante siempre, aun hay bueno sistemas sobre python 2 :D

Comment: @WillyGuevara pero no es mejor tener nuestras aplicaciones actualizadas... Porque tener un sistema antiguo de PHP5 inferior por ejemplo hoy con PHP7 ese sistema estará ejecutando varios errores... Las actualizaciones de software se dan por algo no... :)

Comment: En efecto, pero cuando los sistemas son muy grandes, es un proceso doloroso que se lleva de a poco, paso a paso y mientras tanto usted como desarrollador debe tener alternativas para que mientras sale la actualización el sistema pueda seguir operando sin problemas. @J.Mick

Comment: @WillyGuevara Yo los actualizó siempre, deje ejecutando el trabajo con el código viejo y en un subdominio realizó la actualización ya después en la madrugada realizó la migración :)